# Access 2007: Hide Data Labels on Chart Object via vba with 0 values?

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form in Access 2007 with a Stacked Bar Chart Object that is dynamically generated depending on the current date and outputs a PDF of the chart.

Everything generates and works fine, but what is happening is data labels are being applied even for series with a Null or 0 value. This leads to a mess of text in various places.

I'm looking for a way via VBA to remove any labels that belong to a series with no values.

I've tried ruling out null values from the SQL query and also setting the format options so the 0 values won't show. I have tried looping through the series and applying a label if the value is > 0, but if I set it to apply the series name it still puts it for blank values.

[image]

EDIT Current Code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim tstChart As Graph.Chart

   On Error GoTo Form_Load_Error

Set tstChart = [Forms]!testing!barEquip.Object
With tstChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
    .ChartTitle.Text = VBA.Strings.MonthName(VBA.DatePart("m", VBA.Date()) - 1) & " " &     VBA.DatePart("yyyy", VBA.Date()) & _
                        " Test Title"

    For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
        For Each pt In srs.Points
            pt.DataLabel.Text = "Y"
        Next
    Next
End With

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

Form_Load_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Form_Load of VBA Document Form_testing"

End Sub
```

I'm able to change each label, but I can't seem to figure out a way to check each point in the series points.

EDIT:
**SOLVED**
(Simple, but works fine)

```
Sub AdjustDataLabels(cht As Chart)

Dim srs As Series
Dim pt As Point
Dim vals As Variant

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    'Apply Value labels
    srs.ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowValue)

    For Each pt In srs.Points
        'Check for empty labels
        If pt.DataLabel.Text = "" Then
           'Do nothing
        Else
           'Add Series Name then remove Value
           pt.DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = True
           pt.DataLabel.ShowValue = False
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Series `.HasDataLabels = False`?

Comment: I'll try doing that again, but previous attempts left me with the same problem. It seems to work for all data label types other than the series name.

Comment: Oh Ok... can you add some screenshots (upload to Imgur.com if you don't have enough rep to post them here) so I can see what the issue is?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Jv02Qv2.png It's a stacked bar chart.

Comment: It's a stacked *column* chart :)  Also, those appear to be `Points`, not `Series`.  Not sure what you mean by "series values" unless you mean "point values" (each point has one and only one value, and each series is comprised of at least one point that must have a value).  Also not sure what you mean by "series title"? In any case I think the trick here will be to do `For Each srs in .SeriesCollection`, then `For each pt in `.Points` and adjust each point's `DataLabel.Text` as needed.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology, still learning the ins-n-outs of Access. I already had a loop that was doing just that, but I'm now having trouble getting the specific values so I can set the `DataLabel.Text = ""` Right now I can change the labels only for a column as a whole, so every section of the bar changes to the same text. Is there a way to access the values? Trying to do `...Points(i).value` throws an unsupported property error. `Points(i).Item` ?

Comment: It will be helpful if you revise your Q to include the code you are currently using to mainpulate the chart.  NB: I know ZERO about Access  -- literally zero, I have never used it a second in my life -- but generally speaking since 2007+ the chart objects are pretty much the same across all of the MS Office products, so even though I don't do Access, there's a pretty good chance I can answer or at least point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Updated the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `Graph.Chart` instead of a `Chart`.  They are more limited in what you can do with them, which is what I was afraid of. But perhaps this can help anyways.

The idea is to first ensure that the series data labels are being displayed.

Once we know they are displayed, iterate the points and selectively manipulate the point's `DataLabel.Text` property, based on it's `DataLabel.Text` property. I'm assuming the value here being displayed is `0`, and that you simply want to hide labels if it's `0`, and do nothing to the other labels.

Within your procedure we will call another sub to do this:

```
Set tstChart = [Forms]!testing!barEquip.Object
With tstChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
    .ChartTitle.Text = VBA.Strings.MonthName(VBA.DatePart("m", VBA.Date()) - 1) & " " &     VBA.DatePart("yyyy", VBA.Date()) & _
                        " Test Title"

    Call AdjustDataLabels(tstChart) 'Call a procedure to modify the labels as needed

End With
```

So that code will now call on another sub-procedure:

```
Sub AdjustDataLabels(cht As Graph.Chart)

Dim srs As Graph.Series
Dim pt As Graph.Point
Dim vals As Variant

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    'First, ensure the dataLabels are ON
    srs.ApplyDataLabels
    For Each pt In srs.Points
        'Now, check the datalabels one by one, testing for your criteria
        If pt.DataLabel.Text = " some condition " Then
            'Criteria met, so blank out this datalabel
            'pt.HasDataLabel = False
            'OR:
             pt.DataLabel.Text = vbNullString

        Else
            'If you need to make any adjustments to other labels, 
            ' you can do that here.
            ' For example you could simply append the series name.
            ' Modify as needed.
            pt.DataLabel.Text = pt.DataLabel.Text & " -- " & srs.Name


        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that route and it doesn't seem to work since when the labels are set to Value they won't display 0 or Null values, but when it is set to series it applies them to empty points. I changed the Graph.Chart to the Chart object, anyway of directly accessing each point value instead of the Label text?

Comment: What do you mean "when it is **set to series** it applies them to empty points?  Do ou mean the option whereby you can set the data labels to display the series name *and* value?  If so, you realize you can simply replicate that functionality with the `pt` iteration mentioned above.

Comment: I guess also your screenshot is not as helpful as it could be. The original screenshot clearly showed a bunch of overlapping labels.  What I would like to see is a picture of the **problem** -- in your current screenshot it is not really apparent what the problem is: all points have hte same label "Y", and it doesn't make any sense that way.  Also a picture of what you *want* the end result to look like.

Comment: I want to remove any Label that is representing something that is null. If the labels are set to _Series Name_ then it shows labels for empty points, but if it is set to just value it doesn't show these labels. I added a better picture above. All I want to do is remove those crowded labels that have no reason to be there.

Comment: Right. I don't think you can do that automatically. So forget about setting the series to display Name, set it to display Values. Then you can selectively overwrite the labels with either the null string (if the label is "0") OR the series Name.  This is what VBA is all about my man!!!

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for all your help and getting me pointed in the right direction. Can't say I'll miss VBA once everything is done and I can move on to greener pastures.

Comment: Cheers.  Do consider accepting or upvoting my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:** (Simple, but works fine) Thanks for all the help!

```
Sub AdjustDataLabels(cht As Chart)

Dim srs As Series
Dim pt As Point
Dim vals As Variant

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    'Apply Value labels
    srs.ApplyDataLabels (xlDataLabelsShowValue)

    For Each pt In srs.Points
        'Check for empty labels
        If pt.DataLabel.Text = "" Then
           'Do nothing
        Else
           'Add Series Name then remove Value
           pt.DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = True
           pt.DataLabel.ShowValue = False
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```