# Access 2013: Dynamically modify series label

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a MS Access report with a single Pie Graph on it. Using the Microsoft Graph tool, I've modified the label to display `Series Name, Series Value, Series Percentage` next to each slice of the pie. However, I would like the user to be able to click a check box before the report is launched, allowing them to hide the `Series Value` but leave the `Series Name, Series Percentage`. I can't figure out the VBA to get this to work.

Here's the logic of what I'm trying to do with this chart:

```
If chkHideValues = True Then
   Loop through Series
      ShowSeriesValue = False
   Next
EndIf
```

And here is the GUI dialog displaying the setting I'd like to control with VBA. (Open Graph in design view and double-click on the series).

[image]

Something along these lines:

[Access 2007: Hide Data Labels on Chart Object via vba with 0 values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939169/access-2007-hide-data-labels-on-chart-object-via-vba-with-0-values)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your Chart Object name?/ Have you tried any real VBA code ?

Answer (score 0):

Using ObjectBrowser would be the best bet to find the exact properties you need to modify.

Saying that I guess at one of the more obvious ones to use - let me know if this works for you
(**of course, replace "YourChartName."**)

```
Dim seriesData As Series 

Set seriesData = YourChartName.SeriesCollection("Labels") 

' Turn data labels on or off based on checkbox value
seriesData.HasDataLabels = (Not chkHideValues.Value)
```